# I want to open installed music apps in preview controller using xamarin.forms in iOS, is it possible?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

[image]

What i'm trying to achieve is On button click open all installed music apps in iPhone device and show them in preview dialog box [check the image]. User can select any app and play music in that app.

I have tried to use **MPMediaPickerController** but when I execute app it get crash when the MPMediaPickerController's delegate line executes:

```
MPMediaPickerController mediaPicker = new MPMediaPickerController(MPMediaType.Music);
mediaPicker.AllowsPickingMultipleItems = false;
mediaPicker.ShowsCloudItems = true;
var _musicPlayer = new MPMusicPlayerController();
mediaPicker.Delegate = new MyMediaPickerDelegate(_musicPlayer, this);                
UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(mediaPicker, true, null);
```

From above code when **mediaPicker.Delegate = new MyMediaPickerDelegate(_musicPlayer, this);** get executed it gives below exception:

> The object passed of type
>   MyApp.iOS.Helpers.PlayMusic+MyMediaPickerDelegate does not derive from
>   NSObject

Comment: You can use the Share functionality ,it will open the iOS default share Dialog . Check https://xamarinhelp.com/share-dialog-xamarin-forms/ . And here is a sample about the usage of MusicKit in iOS https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/ios11/MusicKitSample

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT MusicKit will may give access to Apple music app, but what about other app?? how I can make it appear in share dialog and use?